# Relation between minSdkVersion, CompileSdkVersion and ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL for android native library build

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I trying to build an Android native library using a CMakeList.txt file. There is a crash that I am observing when the library is built with minSdkVersion 23 whereas I do not face that issue while building it minSdkVersion as 21 using Android Studio. The problem is I cannot figure out where to change this value or pass an argument while building it through command line. The normal procedure I follow to build the native library is to generate the ninja build files using the cmake command followed by the ninja command but the cmake command does not have any variable to specify the minSdkVersion.

For building the native library using cmake, the only variable that I could find through which we can specify the version is ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL. The documentation (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html) shows that ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL is the version that cmake uses for compilation but the part which is confusing me is that whenever I change the minSdkVersion in the build.gradle file and build it through gradle file, the log file shows that cmake command is using the ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL which is set to the minSdkVersion present in the gradle file. Shouldn't it be set to the value in the CompileSdkVersion?

I just need a way to pass the minSdkVersion variable to the cmake command.What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it should not be `compileSdkVersion`. `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` are Java idioms. Native code behaves differently from Java code (any used function *must* be present at runtime regardless of whether it is actually called). As such `minSdkVersion` *must* be your `ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL`.

See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md#target-api-set-higher-than-device-api.

I assume you're seeing the crash with `minSdkVersion 23` while running on an android-21 device?

Comment: Thanks Dan. Yes I am seeing the crash while running on an android-21 device

Comment: The crash is expected then. `minSdkVersion` is the minimum version your app can work with.